# java- libgdx build.gradle is not the same for AdMob

Tags: java, android, libgdx, admob

i am building an app for android and using libGdx, i checked a million tutorial on how to add Admob, every tutorial requests to adjust the build.gradle file but my file is not the same as theirs, they have Dependencies and different stuff there, any idea how to add admob on my build.gradle?

the android build.gradle:

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    compileSdkVersion 25
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/robovm/ios/robovm.xml'
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.badlogic.drop"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 25
    }
}


// called every time gradle gets executed, takes the native dependencies of
// the natives configuration, and extracts them to the proper libs/ folders
// so they get packed with the APK.
task copyAndroidNatives() { 
    file("libs/armeabi/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/armeabi-v7a/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/arm64-v8a/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/x86_64/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/x86/").mkdirs();

    configurations.natives.files.each { jar ->
        def outputDir = null
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-arm64-v8a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/arm64-v8a")
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi-v7a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi-v7a")        
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi")
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86_64.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86_64")
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86")
        if(outputDir != null) {
            copy {
                from zipTree(jar)
                into outputDir
                include "*.so"
            }
        }
    }
}

task run(type: Exec) {
    def path
    def localProperties = project.file("../local.properties")
    if (localProperties.exists()) {
        Properties properties = new Properties()
        localProperties.withInputStream { instr ->
            properties.load(instr)
        }
        def sdkDir = properties.getProperty('sdk.dir')
        if (sdkDir) {
            path = sdkDir
        } else {
            path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
        }
    } else {
        path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
    }

    def adb = path + "/platform-tools/adb"
    commandLine "$adb", 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-n', 'com.badlogic.drop/com.badlogic.drop.AndroidLauncher'
}

// sets up the Android Eclipse project, using the old Ant based build.
eclipse {
    // need to specify Java source sets explicitly, SpringSource Gradle Eclipse plugin
    // ignores any nodes added in classpath.file.withXml
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs "src", 'gen'
        }
    }

    jdt {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.6
        targetCompatibility = 1.6
    }

    classpath {
        plusConfigurations += [ project.configurations.compile ]        
        containers 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK', 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES'       
    }

    project {
        name = appName + "-android"
        natures 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature'
        buildCommands.clear();
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder"
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder"
        buildCommand "org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder"
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder"
    }
}

// sets up the Android Idea project, using the old Ant based build.
idea {
    module {
        sourceDirs += file("src");
        scopes = [ COMPILE: [plus:[project.configurations.compile]]]        

        iml {
            withXml {
                def node = it.asNode()
                def builder = NodeBuilder.newInstance();
                builder.current = node;
                builder.component(name: "FacetManager") {
                    facet(type: "android", name: "Android") {
                        configuration {
                            option(name: "UPDATE_PROPERTY_FILES", value:"true")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the core build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: "java"

sourceCompatibility = 1.6
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = [ "src/" ]


eclipse.project {
    name = appName + "-core"
}
```

and finally the desktop build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: "java"

sourceCompatibility = 1.6
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = [ "src/" ]

project.ext.mainClassName = "com.badlogic.drop.desktop.DesktopLauncher"
project.ext.assetsDir = new File("../android/assets");

task run(dependsOn: classes, type: JavaExec) {
    main = project.mainClassName
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    standardInput = System.in
    workingDir = project.assetsDir
    ignoreExitValue = true
}

task dist(type: Jar) {
    from files(sourceSets.main.output.classesDir)
    from files(sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir)
    from {configurations.compile.collect {zipTree(it)}}
    from files(project.assetsDir);

    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': project.mainClassName
    }
}

dist.dependsOn classes

eclipse {
    project {
        name = appName + "-desktop"
        linkedResource name: 'assets', type: '2', location: 'PARENT-1-PROJECT_LOC/android/assets'
    }
}

task afterEclipseImport(description: "Post processing after project generation", group: "IDE") {
  doLast {
    def classpath = new XmlParser().parse(file(".classpath"))
    new Node(classpath, "classpathentry", [ kind: 'src', path: 'assets' ]);
    def writer = new FileWriter(file(".classpath"))
    def printer = new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(writer))
    printer.setPreserveWhitespace(true)
    printer.print(classpath)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget build.gradle of desktop and core module.

Hopefully you're using Firebase Admob integration instead of legacy AdMob integration so first integrate Firebase then Admob Ad.

Add this part to [build.gradle](https://github.com/itsabhiaryan/AdService-LibGDX/blob/master/android/build.gradle) of android module.

```
dependencies {

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

In your [build.gradle](https://github.com/itsabhiaryan/AdService-LibGDX/blob/master/build.gradle) file of root project

Add as dependencies in buildscript for firebase integration.

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

Changes in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```

Start Coding part, create view after MobileAds initialisation.

```
MobileAds.initialize(activity.getApplicationContext(), APP_ID);
initView();

protected void initView(){

        // Create and setup the AdMobHelper view
        topView = new AdView(activity);
        topView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        topView.setAdUnitId(TopAdUnitId);

        bottomView = new AdView(activity);
        bottomView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        bottomView.setAdUnitId(BottomAdUnitId);

        AdRequest.Builder adRequestBuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();
        //adRequestBuilder.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR);
        topView.loadAd(adRequestBuilder.build());

        AdRequest.Builder adRequestBuilder1 = new AdRequest.Builder();
        adRequestBuilder1.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR);
        bottomView.loadAd(adRequestBuilder1.build());

        crateInterestial();

        // Do the stuff that initialize() would do for you
        callForInitializeForView();

    }
```

You can check this [project](https://github.com/itsabhiaryan/AdService-LibGDX) for Ad(AdMob with/without Firebase, RevMob, Chartboost, StartApp...) integration with LibGDX.

Comment: Thanks alot for the help, i have 2 questions, first where to add this line "classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'"?
and second where to add the coding part? the last part of your answer where should i write it?

Comment: there is a link of root build.gradle file open it and check where should you need to write.