# Admob ad not visible (Using LibGDX)

Tags: java, android, libgdx, admob

I followed the tutorials both here: 
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdView

And here:
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Admob-in-libgdx

Everything looks like it should show up, but when I launch my app (both on my emulator and an actual device) no ads show up.

Here is my code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;

/**
 * Android's way to initialize the game.
 */
 public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {


private AdView adView;

@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    MobileAds.initialize(this, "################");

    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);

    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();

    View gameView = initializeForView(new DoubleDodge(new AndroidDatabaseAccess()), config);

    // Create and setup the AdMob view
    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId("#############");
    adView.setVisibility(AdView.VISIBLE);

    // Create an ad request.
    AdRequest.Builder adRequestBuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();

    // Optionally populate the ad request builder.
    adRequestBuilder.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR);


    // Add the gameView to the view hierarchy
    layout.addView(gameView);

    // Start loading the ad.
    adView.loadAd(adRequestBuilder.build());


    // Add the AdMob view
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams =
            new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

    // Add the AdView to the view hierarchy.
    layout.addView(adView, adParams);

    // Hook it all up
    setContentView(layout);

    //initialize(new DoubleDodge(new AndroidDatabaseAccess()), config);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // Resume the AdView.
    adView.resume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    // Pause the AdView.
    adView.pause();

    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // Destroy the AdView.
    adView.destroy();

    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java- libgdx build.gradle is not the same for AdMob](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43301569/java-libgdx-build-gradle-is-not-the-same-for-admob)

Answer (score 0):

FIRST:

```
 private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
```

SECOND:

```
   mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
            mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.interstitial_ad_unit_id));
            AdRequest adRequestInter = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAdLoaded() {
                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                }
            });

            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequestInter);
```

OR

```
 AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

HAPPY CODING

Comment: I want banner ads not interstitial ads, and I'm looking to set the location of the ad programmatically without using XML. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. It turns out that only the first round of ads (for the first 60 seconds) wasn't showing. To fix this, I browsed stack overflow and found that setting the background of the adview to Color.TRANSPARENT fixes the issue:

```
adView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Thanks all for the help, and I hope this helps someone else out there.